# Explicit computation of a limit of a cosimplicial object

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\Delta$ be the simplex category. Let $T_{n}$ be the standard topological $n$ simplex, i.e. it is the set of points of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $0\leq t_{1}\leq \dots \leq t_{n}\leq 1$. Its coface maps are the inclusions

$d^{i}(t_{1}, \dots ,t_{n})=(t_{1},\dots ,t_{i},t_{i},\dots ,t_{n})$

for $i=0,\dots n+1$ (we assume $t_{0}=1, t_{n+1}=1$). Its codegenerancy maps are the projections

$s^{i}(t_{1}, \dots ,t_{n})=(t_{1},\dots ,t_{i},t_{i+2},\dots ,t_{n})$

for $i=0,\dots n-1$. Let $F_{n}$ be the algebra of polynomials over $T_{n}$. Then $(F_{*}, d, s)$ has the structure of a simplicial algebra. I know how to write down explicit

$lim_{\Delta^{op}}F_{*}$,

but  I wonder if there is an explict formula for
it that use the fact that it is a limit of a simplicial object over $\Delta^{op}$.

Comment: Do you mean $(F_*, d, s)$ is a _cosimplicial_ algebra? Do you mean $\varprojlim_{\mathbf{\Delta}} F_*$?

Comment: Let $p\in F_{n}$ be a polynomial $p\: : \: T_{n}\to \mathbb{R}$. Then $p\circ d^{i}\: :\:T_{n-1}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial and is in $F_{n-1}$, so it is a "simplicial algebra", it isn't?

Comment: Now I fix the definition above, i see the mistake! Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Yes, you can make $F_*$ into a simplicial algebra that way, but do you still mean $\varprojlim_{\mathbf{\Delta}^\mathrm{op}} F_*$? There is a very easy formula for that, namely $F_0$.

Comment: Yes I mean the inverse limit of the diagram from $\Delta^{op}$ to the category of algebras. How do you prove that? So this algebra is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{R}$!?

Comment: Uh it was super easy! [0] is the inital object inside $\Delta^{op}$. By the way thanks!